# assign property to object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I know there are a lot of questions like this and this is probably a duplicate, but be sure, i tried every single solution provided to these questions and none of them worked for me.

Here's the thing:

I have an array of objects:

```
let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    year: 2022,
    month: 11,
    currentCount: 2460.9,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    year: 2022,
    month: 9,
    currentCount: 2481.4,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    year: 2022,
    month: 2,
    currentCount: 2521.1,
  }
]
```

and i want to loop through the array and add a new property to each object. I tried many different ways (forEach, for-loop, etc) but my latest try was this one:

```
data.map((item, index) => {
    if (prevCount === undefined) {
        //do some things here
    } else {

        //do some things here

        //the new property i want to add
        let newProperty = "foo"
        
        //some methods i tried
        item.newProperty = "foo"
        item[newProperty] = "foo"

        let obj = {newProperty: "foo"}
        let newObj = Object.assign(item, obj)

        //do some things here
    }
})
```

but in the end nothing happens. No error and no new property. I'm getting a bit crazy over this one, because it seems so simple...

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

After changing the map to this:

```
let newData = dataElec.map((item, index) => {
    if (prevCount === undefined) {
        prevCount = item.currentCount
        return item
    } else {
        let meter = {foo: 'bar'}
        return {...item, meter}
    }
})
```

it is kind of working, but i get a weird object structure:
[image: screenshot of array in console]

the object and properties (first red box) are not added by my code. i don't know where they come from. The content/properties of the object "_doc" (second red box) should be on the same level as the "meter" object.

I could work with a structure like this, but i would like a clean array. And I'm wondering how the other objects are getting into my array anyways...

so again, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a problem with `prevCount` not being defined. Other than that, you're doing it right. Try logging `data` after the `map` call. However, when modifying items in an array directly, use forEach instead of map.

```
data.forEach(item => {
  item.foo = 'bar'
})
```

Use map if you want a duplicate array with things changed.
This returns a new array with the key 'foo' added to each object.

```
data.map(item => {
  return { ...item, foo: 'bar' }
})
```

Comment: The second method kind of worked, but i get a weird object structure back. I edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Use the spread operator on `meter` as well since you want to include the keys found in meter, not the meter object itself. `return {...item, ...meter}`

Comment: It came out that the weird structure came from mongoose, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951260/spread-syntax-returns-unexpected-object). I didn't even considered that this could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    year: 2022,
    month: 11,
    currentCount: 2460.9,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    year: 2022,
    month: 9,
    currentCount: 2481.4,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    year: 2022,
    month: 2,
    currentCount: 2521.1,
  }
];
data = data.map((item, index) => {return {...item,foo:"bar"}})
console.log(data);
```

Comment: you just need to use map function and assign back to same or different to save the object in persistence state.

Comment: This kind of worked, but i get a weird object structure back. I edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: That should have work its a weird output not expecting such thing. will require values dataElec list sample object similiar and prevCount variable. or Are you using any JS library.